# Match, delete automatically shift cells to left and report column of matching cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have a table with 11 columns and 5 rows

The Columns are labelled in this manner A ,1 ,2 ,3 ,4 ,5 ,6 ,7 ,8 ,9 ,10 ,ADD

CLA is a Manual Input Cell 
CL1 is always equal to CLA.

A, being the cell that already contains an input in the form of single number.

Given, first row contains a random arrangement of numbers from 0-9

In the next row macro must copy the above row , CL1 to CL0, then it must consider the value in CL1, MATCH it through the same row , if match is found, delete the matched cell and move the cells to left. The Value of CL1 must now be macthed with above row and its address must be reported into ADD column. Address means Column label of the matched cell in the above column. Then Move to next row.

First

CLA CL1 CL2 CL3 CL4 CL5 CL6 CL7 CL8 CL9 CL10      ADD

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0      

 3   3   1   2   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   CL3
```

Then I Input Value in CLA in next row (Manual Input) , 3 in this case .Always cl1 = cla )

It must do this untill all CLA'S Are done with. CLA's are pre filled and cl1's are prefilled too.

EXAMPLE STEPS TO HOW IT MUST BE DONE

**Start -> Copy The Above Row from CL1 TO CL10**

CLA CL1 CL2 CL3 CL4 CL5 CL6 CL7 CL8 CL9 CL10      ADD

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0      

 3   3   1   2   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   CL3

 6
```

**-> Put them in CL2 ( I will Input CLA and CL1 has this prefilled formula =CL1=CLA**

CLA CL1 CL2 CL3 CL4 CL5 CL6 CL7 CL8 CL9 CL10      ADD

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0      

 3   3   1   2   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   CL3

 6   6   3   1   2   4   5   6   7   8   9   0    ( Copied from above in CL2 )
```

**-> Match the CL1 value in the copied row and delete that cell and move cells left.**

CLA CL1 CL2 CL3 CL4 CL5 CL6 CL7 CL8 CL9 CL10      ADD

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0      

 3   3   1   2   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   CL3

 6   6   3   1   2   4   5   7   8   9   0    ( 6 is deleted because it matches with cl1 in same row )
```

**-> Now go to ADD column and match CL1 In in the above row, and Report the Column of the Matching cell. ADD is CL4 in this case because 3 , which is CL1 In present row, was on CL4 in the above row.**

CLA CL1 CL2 CL3 CL4 CL5 CL6 CL7 CL8 CL9 CL10      ADD

```
     1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   0      

 3   3   1   2   4   5   6   7   8   9   0   CL4

 6   6   3   1   2   4   5   7   8   9   0   CL7  ( Add is CL7 because 6 was in CL7 IN THE ABOVE ROW)
```

Comment: I understand the concept but I want to understand the column part as it seems that the ADD column is reporting 1 column over from the actual location is this the desired functionality? e.g. 3 is actually in the `CL3` position not `CL4`.

Comment: @engineersmnky yes, it was C3 thank you. Yes, I have pre filled inputs in CLA and I want the code to copy the above row to cl2, match cla/cl1 ( both are equal ), delete the duplicate one in the row, that is cl1's match, report the cl1's match on the above row to ADD. So, when I give a table with prefilled CLA coulmn, the whole table must be worked out in the manner. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what Ive been using for now. Im not a VBA expert and I know this is bad coding. But as per the solution, it is perfect. It deals with 12 Columns. Its a bit slow. As it goes step by step. Any suggestions to speed up code processing is welcome. Thanks

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim X As Integer
Dim A As Integer
Dim R As Integer
Dim D As Integer
'Two variables will do the work
X = 2
A = 2
D = 1
R = 2
'Adjust COUNTER as per need of Columns that need to be processed
For COUNTER = 1 To 6
Cells(X, 1).Select
Selection.Copy
Cells(A, 2).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Range(Cells(D, 2), Cells(D, 13)).Select
Selection.Copy
Cells(X, 3).Select
ActiveSheet.Paste 
'Adress Section
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 3) Then Cells(R, 16).Value = 1
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 4) Then Cells(R, 16).Value = 2
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 5) Then Cells(R, 16).Value = 3
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 6) Then Cells(R, 16).Value = 4
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 7) Then Cells(R, 16).Value = 5
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 8) Then Cells(R, 16).Value = 6
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 9) Then Cells(R, 16).Value = 7
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 10) Then Cells(R, 16).Value = 8
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 11) Then Cells(R, 16).Value = 9
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 12) Then Cells(R, 16).Value = 10
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 13) Then Cells(R, 16).Value = 11
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 14) Then Cells(R, 16).Value = 12

'DeleteSection
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 3) Then Cells(R, 3).Delete xlToLeft
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 4) Then Cells(R, 4).Delete xlToLeft
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 5) Then Cells(R, 5).Delete xlToLeft
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 6) Then Cells(R, 6).Delete xlToLeft
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 7) Then Cells(R, 7).Delete xlToLeft
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 8) Then Cells(R, 8).Delete xlToLeft
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 9) Then Cells(R, 9).Delete xlToLeft
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 10) Then Cells(R, 10).Delete xlToLeft
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 11) Then Cells(R, 11).Delete xlToLeft
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 12) Then Cells(R, 12).Delete xlToLeft
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 13) Then Cells(R, 13).Delete xlToLeft
If Cells(R, 2) = Cells(R, 14) Then Cells(R, 14).Delete xlToLeft
X = X + 1
A = A + 1
D = D + 1
R = R + 1
Next COUNTER
End
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this works for me could use some error handling and adaptation based on your comment but give it a shot it works for manual entry in CLA

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim CLA As Integer
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
            CLA = Target.Value      
            Range("$B$" & Target.Row - 1, "$K$" & Target.Row - 1).Copy Destination:=Range("$C$" & Target.Row)
            Dim lcell As Range
            Dim previous_location As String
            Dim removable As String
            For Each lcell In Range("$C$" & Target.Row, "$K$" & Target.Row)
                If lcell = CLA Then
                    previous_location = Cells(1, lcell.Column - 1)
                    removable = lcell.Address
                    Cells(lcell.Row, 2) = CLA
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next lcell
            Range(removable).Delete
            Cells(Target.Row, "L") = previous_location
    End If
End Sub
```